# Add css file when editing specific content type

Tags: nodes, theming

I would like to add a css file when editing content of the content type invoice.

The link is something like this: `node/121/edit` . I've tried it with it with preprocess_node like this:

```
function themename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $node = $variables['node'];
    if($node->type == 'invoice')
    {
        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . "/css/add.css", array('weight' => 1003));
    }
}
```

But he doesn't add the css file. When I do a `die;` in the if structure he executes it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting the incorrect preprocess function. By the time preprocess_node is run all our JS and CSS has been included in the top of our html document already.

Use this function instead:

[template_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)

Comment: But I can't figure out which node type I'm editing with the preprocess_html function ..

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is wrong - templates work outside-in. `drupal_add_css()` in a node preprocess hook has always worked for me. Ironically, using `drupal_add_css` in `template_preprocess_html`, _definitely_ won't work.